# Load time pondering - Images and Domains

Tags: html, image, download, load-time

So I'm in the process of adding links to images on my web site, and I've come across something interesting.

All the images I'm linking to are housed on another domain, but this domain happens to be located on the same server as the site I'm working on. Now normally I would download images from the other domain and place them in my website's directory structure, so as to avoid having to connect to another server and thus save on load time when grabbing the images on page load. But in this case, with the two file structures being located on the same server, I wonder if the time to download the images on page load would be virtually the same with absolute linking to the 'sibling' domain versus storing the images on my site itself.

Does anybody know if this is the case?? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here's where your thinking goes astray:

> Now normally I would download images from the other domain and place
>   them in my website's directory structure, so as to avoid having to
>   connect to another server and thus save on load time when grabbing the
>   images on page load.

This is not true.  It doesn't save load time to have all the images on the same server.  The browser is the client making the request for the image.  The server to which the browser makes the request doesn't matter.